# ExpressJS Session Cookies Edited Via Post Don't Save

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, session-cookies

I'm quite confused here. I can edit and read cookies whenever there is a get request, but if I edit that cookie via a post, it does not save:

```
    // GET    
    exports.index = function(req, res) {
     req.session.teststore = "This is set from a GET";
     console.log('Reading from a cookie..... :::' , req.session.teststore);
     res.render('index');
    };   

    // Outputs: 'Reading from a cookie..... ::: , 'This is set from a GET'


    exports.page2 = function(req, res) {
     console.log('Reading from a cookie..... :::' , req.session.teststore);
     res.render('page2');
     res.end();
    };

    // Outputs: 'Reading from a cookie..... ::: , 'This is set from a GET'


   //POST
   exports.update = function (req,res) {
    console.log('the value of this cookie is ::: ' , req.session.teststore);
    req.session.teststore = "This is set from a POST"; 
    console.log('the value of this cookie is ::: ' , req.session.teststore);};
    res.send(200);
   }

   // Outputs: 
   the value of this cookie is :::  This is set from a GET
   the value of this cookie is :::  This is set from a POST

    //GET
    exports.page3 = function(req, res) {
     console.log('Reading from a cookie..... :::' , req.session.teststore);
     res.render('page3');
     res.end();
    };

    // Outputs: 'Reading from a cookie..... ::: , 'This is set from a GET'
```

I'm confused because I would expect the GET request for page 3 to see the cookie was updated. Just to confirm, the cookie was set only once in the '/' index request and then altered only in the Post request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why doesn't `exports.update` have any sort of `res.render()` or `res.end()`?

Comment: I took it out to make the example brief. It has a 'res.send(200);' Perhaps that is the issue.... I'll update it.